# PostgreSQL Multi-Word-String comparison times out

Tags: postgresql, search

I am trying to run a search of approximately 10 million rows against `primary_entity_name`.  However, each time `fq` has a space, the query times out.

```
// "dog" works
// "walking dog" times out

select *
from companies
where primary_entity_name LIKE '%walking dog%'
limit 10
```

**explain ( analyze on, buffers on )**

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..21551.17 rows=10 width=1542) (actual time=52210.872..269801.658 rows=6 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1429 read=2115468
  ->  Seq Scan on companies  (cost=0.00..2247787.26 rows=1043 width=1542) (actual time=52210.871..269801.644 rows=6 loops=1)
      Filter: ((primary_entity_name)::text ~~ '%walking dog%'::text)
      Rows Removed by Filter: 10471215
      Buffers: shared hit=1429 read=2115468
Planning time: 0.113 ms
Execution time: 269801.687 ms
```

**Query plan**

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..41950.28 rows=10 width=1569)
  ->  Seq Scan on companies  (cost=0.00..1959078.25 rows=467 width=1569)
    Filter: ((primary_entity_name)::text ~~ '%walking dog%'::text)
```

Comment: You should take the actual queries, run them with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and post the two plans.

Comment: Thanks - Please see above @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a coincidence that you observed the long duration with a search word containing a space. Try a couple of times with different strings.

It could be that the *length* of the search term has some influence, but the overwhelming performance hog in that query is I/O.

From the execution plan you can see that the query has to read about 16 GB from the disk and scan 10 million rows to find the 6 matching ones. That cost will stay the same no matter what your search pattern is, as long as it starts with a `%`.

If you *really* need to search for strings in the middle of a string, you should look at PostgreSQL's full text search capabilities which address exactly the use case you show in your example. If you need to match strings in the middle of words as well, things get harder – you might want to check out `pg_trgm`.

Comment: When I only `select 'primary_entity_name'` the query time reduces to less than two seconds.

Comment: How does the query look and what is its execution plan?

Comment: Added the query plan to the original post.